# Azure Mobile Service: Unable to load the specified metadata resource

Tags: entity-framework, azure

I published my Azure Mobile Service and suddenly I got this error. I use a code first approach and I have not changed my models.

```
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "Unable to load the specified metadata resource.",
"exceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException",
"stackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)\r\n
```

I m using EF 6.1.1 and my connection string is defined for the System.Data.SqlClientProvider.

It works fine when I run locally against my MSSQLLocalDB.

Anyone knows why EF attempts to load a Metadata even if I am using a code first approach? What should I do to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it was my connection string which was modified when the code was built in release environment. This issue was caused by a refactory.